# Is there something similar to TabControlRegionAdapter.ItemContainerStyle Attached Property for ItemsControl?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, prism-4

I'm using Prism 4 with Silverlight and I want to use ItemsControl to host multiple views. I really want all the views to be wrapped inside a specified ItemTemplate or be able to specify an ItemStyle so that I can use something like the Expander control in the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl4/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html) . When I try to specify an ItemTemplate an unhandled     System.NotSupportedException is thrown at runtime.

```
ItemsControl.Items must not be a UIElement type when an ItemTemplate is set.
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.MS.Internal.Controls.IGeneratorHost.GetContainerForItem(Object item, DependencyObject recycledContainer)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.Generator.GenerateNext(Boolean stopAtRealized, Boolean& isNewlyRealized)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.IItemContainerGenerator.GenerateNext(Boolean& isNewlyRealized)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.AddContainers()
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.RecreateVisualChildren(IntPtr unmanagedObj)
```

Code

```
<ItemsControl Regions:RegionManager.RegionName="DetailsRegion">
     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
              <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
           </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: How are you setting the ItemsSource? Based on the Exception it sounds like you're explicitly adding the items to the items control (itemsControl.itemsControl.Items.Add()) instead of setting the ItemsSource, usually via Binding or your could do it via Codebehind (itemscontrol.ItemsSource = myCollection).

Comment: I'm not setting the ItemsSource in the Xaml. I'm using the default ItemsControlRegionAdapter in Prism4. It sets the ItemsSource in void Adapt(IRegion region, ItemsControl regionTarget) to this: regionTarget.ItemsSource = region.Views. region.Views is IViewsCollection : IEnumerable<object>, INotifyCollectionChanged. Nothing too crazy going on here...

Comment: Do you know what's on the collection? I think that might be the problem since SL knows that's already an element it might just try to render it instead of using it as the DataContext for your DataTemplate.

Comment: Do you mean what is 'in' the collection? Nothing is in the collection at the point the exception is thrown.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 'in'. 
Looks like PRISM is adding something to the collection. The exception clearly refers to an item. Could you somehow  subscribe to CollectionChange events? I think you will have to write your own IRegion that wraps the element into another content.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I used PRISM, but the following is an example that you can use to implement a custom IRegion that wraps the element before adding it to the collection.

```
public class RegionWrapper : Region
{
    public override Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Regions.IRegionManager Add(object view, string viewName, bool createRegionManagerScope)
    {
        var myWrapper = new Wrapper();
        myWrapper.Content = view;
        return base.Add(myWrapper, viewName, createRegionManagerScope);
    }
}
```

To register this item you need to create a Region factory, which in PRISM they call an adapter

```
public class RegionWrapperAdapter : RegionAdapterBase<IRegionAdapter>
{
    protected override Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Regions.IRegion CreateRegion()
    {
        return new RegionWrapper();
    }
}
```

Then on your Bootstrap just register your adapter

```
    protected override RegionAdapterMappings ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings()
    {
        var regionAdapterMappings = base.ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings();
        regionAdapterMappings.RegisterMapping(typeof(ItemsControl), Container.Resolve<RegionWrapperAdapter>());
        return regionAdapterMappings;
    }
```

Of course the other part left is to implement the control 'Wrapper' so you can create that class and add the content. It could simply be a ContentControl with a particular style similar to what you have in this example or add anything fancier.

This code is based on an old version of PRISM, so things might have changed recently.

Hope this helps

Miguel